# React.js | what is different beetween this two functions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

I have a checkbox `<input type='checkbox' onClick={ this.props.isTicked.bind(this,id)} />`
I also have to do tasks:

```
  state = {
    todos: [
      {
        id:1,
        title: 'Earn 10 lvl Faceit',
        completed: false
      },
      {
        id:2,
        title: 'Achieve 10 badges',
        completed: false
      }
    ]
  }
```

So id of checkbox equals id of its task. Then i want to make 'isTicked' function to make completed be an opposite value. I also have style for every task(that is different for true and false)

```
            <div style ={this.TaskStyle()}>

                <p>
                    <input type='checkbox' onClick={ this.props.isTicked.bind(this,id)} />
                    {title}
                </p>
            </div>
```

TaskStyle:

```
    TaskStyle = () => {
        if (this.props.task_value.completed) {
            return {

                backgroundColor: 'darkgreen',
                fontFamily: 'Arial',
                padding:'10px'
            }
        }
        else {
            return {
                backgroundColor: 'gray',
                fontFamily: 'Arial',
                padding:'10px'
            }
        }

        }
```

Back to the point, this is a working version of 'isTicked':

```
    this.setState({todos: this.state.todos.map(todo => {
      if (todo.id === id) {
        todo.completed = !todo.completed
      }
      return todo
    })})
```

And this is mine and i dont know why it is not working....

```
  isTicked = (id) => {
    this.state.todos.forEach(todo => {
      if (todo.id === id) {
        todo.completed = !todo.completed
      }
      return todo
    });
  }
```

Can someone help me?)

Comment: forEach doesn't return anything, map does. You want to return an array and with forEach you aren't returning anything. forEach is normally used to call stuff on each element that you don't need the return value from :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, firstly in your `isTicked` function, you're not setting the state like the previous method does.

Secondly, `map` returns a new Array which you san set as a newState while `forEach` does not. In fact that's the only difference between the two.

Now when you're iterating though `forEach` and directly changing the state, React doesn't have a way to know that the state has changed and it has to trigger the `render` function. Hence, you're not seeing the changes in the other case. On the other hand, in the former case, when you're modifying the state though `setState`, React re-renders the component in turn and you see the effect.

*It's as simple as that :)*

> Do Not Modify State Directly For example, this will not re-render a
>   component:

```
// Wrong
this.state.comment = 'Hello';
// Instead, use setState():

// Correct
this.setState({comment: 'Hello'});
```

You might like to read this: [do-not-modify-state-directly](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly)

Answer (score 0):

You are manipulating state directly in this code:

```
isTicked = (id) => {
    this.state.todos.forEach(todo => {
      if (todo.id === id) {
        todo.completed = !todo.completed
      }
      return todo
    });
  }
```

which can introduce all kind of unwanted behaviour (=bugs) into your code, as it circumvents Reacts state management. The first implementation is better, but not perfect, as through some weird coincidence the state you are mapping over could change. It would be better to use the *callback* syntax of `setState`:

```
this.setState(prevState => {
  const newState = prevState.todos.map(todo => {
    if (todo.id === id) {
      todo.completed = !todo.completed;
    }
    return todo;
  });

  return { ...prevState, newState };
});
```

This should ensure that no side effects occur. Maybe this [article](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/get-pro-with-react-setstate-in-10-minutes-d38251d1c781/) is helpful for you.

Also, [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) returns a new value with the mapped over values while [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) just maps over all values, returning nothing.